# Unable to get Jquery Smooth scrolling to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, smooth-scrolling

I have been pulling my hair out trying to get functional smooth scrolling to ids on the same page.  I have tried just about every solution I have found on google.  I get to a point where when it seems everything should work but then even the basic non-js id linking breaks. I am currently using the smooth-scrolling plugin downloaded from the jquery website. The code as it currently stands is such.  I don't know a ton about JS or Jquery so I assume I am just missing something.  I inspecting the code on functional versions of the smooth scrolling but even when 
I do the in-page linking breaks entirely:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Simon Moon Landings</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Noticia+Text:400,700,400italic,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.smooth-scroll.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('ul.mainnav a').smoothScroll();
    });

  </script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">

<div class="menu">
<nav>
<ul class="mainnav">
<li><a href="#one">one</a></li>
<li><a href="#two">two</a></li>
<li><a href="#three">three</a></li>
<li><a href="#four">four</a></li>
<li><a href="#five">five</a></li>
<li><a href="#six">six</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
<img class="logo" src="images/smlogo.gif" width="450" height="288" alt="Simon Moon Landings Logo" onmouseover="on();" onmouseout="off();"></nav>
</div>

<div class="content">

<div class="section" id="one">
<h4>One</h4>

</div>
<div class="section" id="two">
<h4>Two</h4>

</div>
<div class="section" id="three">
<h4>Three</h4>

</div>
<div class="section" id="four">
<h4>Four</h4>

</div>
<div class="section">
<a id="five"><h4>Five</h4></a>

</div>
<div class="section">
<a id="six"><h4>six</h4></a>

</div>
</div>

</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem.  It was not in the script at all, but in the CSS.  I have a two column layout, the menu and anchors are in one column (.menu) and the target divs are in another column (.content)  I applied poisiton:fixed to the menu and it started working.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine here.

Make sure that the URL of jquery-smooth-scroll is correct.

I used this copy of jquery-smooth-scroll to test your code: https://github.com/kswedberg/jquery-smooth-scroll

Answer (score 0):

It works for me. See this example: http://jsbin.com/ixefet/1/edit

All I did was change the `src` for the smooth scroll JavaScript to the online version (https://raw.github.com/kswedberg/jquery-smooth-scroll/master/jquery.smooth-scroll.min.js) and add some text so you can see the scrolling happen.

Sounds like you're using the wrong `src` for your smooth scroll script (if that's the case, your JavaScript error log should say `undefined function: $.smoothScroll` or something like that).

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me while testing on jsfiddle,

```
here you go
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mastermindw/XvV9W/1/